# Change formatting when runserver starts in Django

Tags: django, pycharm

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 03, 2020 - 16:56:57
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'my_project.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I want to write some custom message here, can i do this, just for fun sake i want to use `cowpy` library here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing, if you really need to do that. It's not really meant to be done, though, and it might break "warranties", especially if you upgrade Django...

You can find that banner [over here in the Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b68b8cb89abb35ff2152175ea540619ec384b1f4/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L124-L135).

Likely the easiest way to override it is to override the `runserver` management command with one of your own.

- Add `my_project` as the first entry of your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- Create `my_project/management/commands/runserver.py` (and all the `__init__.py` files in the package directories):

```
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as OriginalRunServerCommand
# NB: if you use `staticfiles`, use 
# from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver import Command as OriginalRunServerCommand


class Command(OriginalRunServerCommand):
    def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
        # copy-paste all of the original inner_run here, and change the bits you require.
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer i'll, try it asap